# When does a question become "protectible"?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, protection

Right after reaching 15k reputation points, I was asking myself about how to do to protect questions. Then, during some review process, I discovered that a question had a "protect" button right after the "share cite edit close flag" usual ones, so I did what was natural to do.

Since then, no other question that I have stumbled upon had this "protect" button, which leads me to ask:

> what are the criteria according to which the SE software considers a question protrectible and inserts the corresponding button?

Comment: This is explained in the help center: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions // "I did what was natural to do." I hope it was "ask this question," and not "click protect." ;-)

Comment: @quid: No, you have misunderstood my question: I am not asking when I should protect a question, I am asking when the SE system offers me the possibility to do it by inserting the appropriate button on a page. Not all questions have the "protect" button available for us to press, check for yourself. Anyway, it seems that the page that you direct me to is a bit outdated, since there have been some recent changes in the protection procedure. Somebody had the same question as me, I'm closing now this post as a duplicate.

Comment: I know this. I do not think the page is outdated. (In fact I had checked beforehand.) From the link: "Any question *at least a day old* can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege, **provided the question has received at least one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation.**"